# how i can display date to textfield when click the button using action sheet

Tags: ios

Button click event

```
- (IBAction)datebutton:(id)sender {


    UIActionSheet *actionSheet1=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Birth Date added !!!!!!"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Add Birth Date",@"OK" ,nil];

    [actionSheet1 showInView:self.view];


}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
        {

            NSDate  *selected=[_datePicker date];
            NSString *message=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"date and time like:%@",selected];

            //dateTextField.text=message;


     //UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     //[alert show];
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {

        }
            break;
            case 2:
        {
             [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
            break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://journeytoios.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/nsdate-vs-nsstring-vice-versa/). It offers a `category` that helps to convert date and string to vice versa. You need to parse the `NSDate` object here as per the `format` and then assign to some `UITextField` or `UILabel`

**EDIT:**

You have parsed the date successfully, but did not assigned `message` variable to `UITextField`, you code should look like:

```
case 0:
{

    NSDate  *selected=[_datePicker date];
    NSString *message=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"date and time like:%@",selected];

    // Assign to the control here
    yourTextField.text = message;
}
```

Comment: actually this code work on alert view but i want to display date on textfield after click on action sheet button ???? i used date picker

Comment: NSDate  *selected=[_datePicker date];
            NSString *message=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"date and time like:%@",selected];
            dateTextField.text=message;

Comment: NSDate  *selected=[_datePicker date];
            NSString *message=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"date and time like:%@",selected];
            dateTextField.text=message;
i assign that..... but its not displaying when i use alert view then it is display ....

Comment: NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
         [_datePicker setDate:now animated:YES];
            NSDate  *selected=[_datePicker date];
            NSString *message=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"date and time like:%@",selected];
            
            dateTextField.text=message;

Comment: It is displaying text on textfield in my code. Make sure your textfield is connected with the outlet.

Comment: all outlet and action are connected .. have any conversion error ??because date display in number format  i write 'dateTextField.text=message' this statement